# How to get optional language parameter from URL in Express routes?

Tags: node.js, express, localization, routes

I'm stuck with a stupid problem:
How to work with *optional* locale parameter?

That's what I mean:

For example, I have *frontpage* and *contacts*, here is routes:

```
app.get('/', frontpage.get);
app.get('/contacts', contacts.get);
```

Now I'm trying to add localization to my site

```
app.all('/:lang?*', language.all); -> detect and set locale
app.get('/:lang?', frontpage.get);
app.get('/:lang?/contacts', contacts.get);
```

The only problem is when I don't use lang-parameter in URL:

```
mysite.com/contacts
```

because Express uses **'contacts'** as a language parameter.
(+ I don't like this copy-pasted `:lang?`)

I think, I just took the wrong way.

How to use locale parameter from URL in Express?

PS: I dont want to use subdomains `de.mysite.com` or querystring `mysite.com?lang=de`. I want exactly this variant `mysite.com/de`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Most modules use [`Accept-Language`](https://github.com/mozilla/i18n-abide) so I can't find any that use the path like this that you might be able to use. So you'll need to define your own middleware that initializes before everything else. Express's `Router` doesn't really help for your usecase.

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    var match = req.url.match(/^\/([A-Z]{2})([\/\?].*)?$/i);
    if (match){
        req.lang = match[1];
        req.url = match[2] || '/';
    }
    next();
});
```

Now you can use `req.lang` in your routes or other middleware to configure your translation logic and since we have rewritten the URL, later logic will not know that there is a language param.