# Optional locale parameter expressjs

Tags: node.js, express, internationalization

I'd like to do an optional locale parameter in my url like this :

- domain.tld/ => best supported locale
- domain.tld/fr/ => force "fr" as locale

So, I've done something like this :

```
app.use("/:locale?/", routes.Index);
```

But I have a problem when trying to get domain.tld/register/ because "register" is considered the asked locale.

Does anyone has an idea for doing this ?

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get optional language parameter from URL in Express routes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22883014/how-to-get-optional-language-parameter-from-url-in-express-routes)

Comment: Do you mean total duplicate ? ... I'll give a try to that solution.

Comment: Ok, it works like a charm. I'm quite new to express and didn't know modifying req.url would affect express routing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone want to know what I did, here is my express middleware :

```
"use strict";

var locale = require("locale");
module.exports = function (supportedLanguages, defaultLocale) {

    // Creation of the list of supported locales
    var supportedLocales = new locale.Locales(supportedLanguages);
    locale.Locale.default = defaultLocale;

    return function (req, res, next) {
        var matches,
            askedLocale = null,
            bestLocale = null,
            locales = null,
            url = null;
        // Test if locale in url 
        matches = req.url.match(/^\/([a-zA-Z]{2})([\/\?].*)?$/i);
        // If locale defined in url
        if (matches !== null) {
            // Get locale
            askedLocale = matches[1].toLowerCase();
            // Modify url for express logic
            req.url = matches[2] || '/';
        }
        // If the asked locale is supported
        if (askedLocale !== null && supportedLanguages.indexOf(askedLocale) !== -1) {
            locales = new locale.Locales(askedLocale);
        } else {
            // Get locale from headers
            locales = new locale.Locales(req.headers["accept-language"]);
        }
        // Getting the best supported locale
        bestLocale = locales.best(supportedLocales).toString();
        // If the asked locale is not the best supported
        if (askedLocale !== null && askedLocale !== bestLocale) {
            // Creation of the new url
            url = "https://" + req.headers.host + "/" + bestLocale + req.url;
            // Redirection to the new locale
            res.redirect(302, url);
        } else {
            // Else if already best locale
            req.setLocale(bestLocale);
            res.locals.locale = req.getLocale();
            // Continue
            next();
        }
    };
};
```

And I call it like this :

```
// Internationalization
app.use(i18n.init);
app.use(localeRedirection(supportedLocales, defaultLocale));
```

with "supportedLocales" as an array of locales and "defaultLocale" as the default locale.